# Configuration option 'xp_cmdshell' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-job

We have a full and diff restore db job created and it is failing with the below error. We have a production server which run the full DB back up SQL jobs of all the DB's and saves them in a different server(example server X) on the server X we  restore sql jobs created and when I run them they are failing with this error:

> Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 1 to 1.
>   Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15457)
>
> Configuration option 'xp_cmdshell' changed from 1 to 1.
>   Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15457)

Can anyone please assist on this?

Comment: Does your script have `EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;` in it?

Comment: There is no error in your question. What you say is an error isn't.

Comment: Nick.Mc Dermaid : Yes we have EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1; in the Script.